# Javascript clean window.postMessage after browser going back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, postmessage

I'm communicating an iframe with an angular controller using window.postMessage function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#The_dispatched_event

The JS that is inside my iframe is as simple as this.

```
//Call this function after clicking button
function runOperationFromExternal(operationId){
    console.log('Button clicked');
    window.parent.postMessage({message: {operation: operationId}}, '*');
}
```

After that I have a service in angular

```
var angular = require('angular');

var ListenerActionsServiceModule = angular.module('ui.apps.myApp.service',[

])

.service('listenerActionService', function($window, $rootScope){
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;

    this.subscribeBeltEvent = function(){
        $window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
            if(event.origin === 'http://localhost:33333') {
                propagateEvent(event);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Origin not allowed');
            }
        }, false);
    };

    function propagateEvent(event) {
        var eventName = 'eventName.';
        var args;
        if(event !== null && typeof event.data.message === 'object') {
            eventName = eventName.concat('complexOperation');
            args = event.data.message.operation;
        }
        else {
            eventName = eventName.concat(event.data.message); 
        }
        $rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, args);
    }
});

module.exports = ListenerActionsServiceModule;
```

Everything is working fine except that, when I click the button inside the iframe the second or third time, the angular service is receiving twice or three times the event. It's like they are stacking in the window and after reading them they are not dissapearing. Is there any way to clean this after reading them? Or should I add to my event a field to know if I have read it or not?

Thank you

**EDIT: This is happening only when we go back using the browser arrow**

Comment: do you use `$window.addEventListener` inside of controller / directive? Could you post the full code of this controller / directive?

Comment: I'm using it inside an angular service I will add the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but your postMessage will never work unless you call your service.

In my case, I usually put an `addEventListener` in the main module and more specifically in the `run` method.

Comment: I'm subscribed correctly from a controller and it's working. My problem is when I go back using the browser back button, if the user click the button inside the iframe, the postMessage comes twice, three times, four times, and so on like if it were stacking